# Query to import from Oracle to MySQL returning null object

Tags: php, mysql, oracle

I'm inserting data from oracle database to mysql database with php than insert and update, but I have a strange behaviour. The table oracle have 20851 records.

The problem is, in the record x, the query to mysql return me a empty result object, but the same query executed on MySQL returned objects with data.

With the following code I can insert and update data from oracle to mysql.

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM B_PROGRAMA_EVALUACION_BIPS'); //oracle db
oci_execute($stid); //oracle db

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

$sql = "select ID_ITEM, ID_PROGRAMA from B_PROGRAMA_EVALUACION_BIPS WHERE ID_ITEM=".$row['ID_ITEM']." AND ID_PROGRAMA=".$row['ID_PROGRAMA'];

$result = $db->query($sql);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if ($rows['ID_ITEM'] == $row['ID_ITEM'] && $rows['ID_PROGRAMA'] == $row['ID_PROGRAMA'])      {
    $sql = "UPDATE B_PROGRAMA_EVALUACION_BIPS SET ID_PROGRAMA='".$row['ID_PROGRAMA'] . "', ANO='" . $row['ANO'] . "', COPIA='" . $row['COPIA'] . "', TIPO_PROGRAMA_ER='"
            . $row['TIPO_PROGRAMA_ER'] . "', EVALUACION='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $row['EVALUACION'])."', ID_CARACTERICACION='".$row['ID_CARACTERICACION']."', NOTA='".$row['NOTA']."' WHERE ID_ITEM=".$row['ID_ITEM'];


} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO B_PROGRAMA_EVALUACION_BIPS VALUES('".$row['ID_PROGRAMA'] . "','" . $row['ANO'] . "','" . $row['COPIA'] . "','"
            . $row['ID_ITEM'] . "','".$row['ID_CARACTERICACION']."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $row['EVALUACION'])."','".$row['TIPO_PROGRAMA_ER']."','".$row['NOTA']."')";
}

$result = $db->query($sql); 

if ($result != 1) {
    $resultado['B_PROGRAMA_EVALUACION_BIPS'] = $resultado['B_PROGRAMA_EVALUACION_BIPS'] + 1;
}
```

}

If I delete this line the second execute query, the first query working perfectly.

```
$result = $db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add single quotes around the values:

```
$sql = "select ID_ITEM, ID_PROGRAMA from B_PROGRAMA_EVALUACION_BIPS WHERE ID_ITEM='".$row['ID_ITEM']."' AND ID_PROGRAMA='".$row['ID_PROGRAMA']"'";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the single quotes, but the error persist. the curious than delete this line $result = $db->query($sql) of second query for insert or update, the first query working perfectly.